# Evaluate a number filled with function calls to a single decimal

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm trying to reduce a number down to a single decimal value that I can actually understand easily. One example of the number is:

```
value = 1/9 (Sqrt[Pow[2, -0.498733] + Pow[2, -0.0241853]] + Sqrt[
   Pow[2, -0.478183] + Pow[2, -0.00964183]] + Sqrt[
   Pow[2, -0.0488264] + Pow[2, -0.006585]] + Sqrt[
   Pow[2, -0.466565] + Pow[2, -0.00593082]] + Sqrt[
   Pow[2, -0.0478234] + Pow[2, 0.037981]] + Sqrt[
   Pow[2, 0.043796] + Pow[2, 0.0486829]] + Sqrt[
   Pow[2, -0.00628231] + Pow[2, 0.524996]] + Sqrt[
   Pow[2, -0.0339185] + Pow[2, 0.54385]] + Sqrt[
   Pow[2, -0.00782349] + Pow[2, 0.56968]])
```

I want to be able to get something like

```
value = 0.0162
```

Edit: 0.0162 is not the actual answer. I haven't calculated it yet

I tried using N[] and NumberForm[] but I'm a bit lost. I'm fine with the answer being to a certain level of precision, as long as I know what that is.

Thanks in advance, and sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: What is the definition of `Pow`?

Comment: @JohnDoty It's the power function that comes inbuilt with Mathematica, just raising a number to a power.

Comment: That's `Power`, not `Pow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

```
1/9 (Sqrt[Pow[2, -0.498733] + Pow[2, -0.0241853]] + 
    Sqrt[Pow[2, -0.478183] + Pow[2, -0.00964183]] + 
    Sqrt[Pow[2, -0.0488264] + Pow[2, -0.006585]] + 
    Sqrt[Pow[2, -0.466565] + Pow[2, -0.00593082]] + 
    Sqrt[Pow[2, -0.0478234] + Pow[2, 0.037981]] + 
    Sqrt[Pow[2, 0.043796] + Pow[2, 0.0486829]] + 
    Sqrt[Pow[2, -0.00628231] + Pow[2, 0.524996]] + 
    Sqrt[Pow[2, -0.0339185] + Pow[2, 0.54385]] + 
    Sqrt[Pow[2, -0.00782349] + Pow[2, 0.56968]]) /. Pow -> Power
(* 1.42943 *)
```

Comment: But he got the result 0.0162! So pow is not Power

Comment: @m.bubu Sorry the number 0.0162 wasn't the actual answer, I should have made that clear... I hadn't evaluated the number yet